# How Do I List Objects in Oracle Object Storage When the Objects Have a Prefix?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex Rest data sources and tried the URLs below

```
https://objectstorage.location.oraclecloud.com/n/namespace/b/bucket/o/  works shows all 4
https://objectstorage.location.oraclecloud.com/n/namespace/b/bucket/o/aabb not found
https://objectstorage.location.oraclecloud.com/n/namespace/b/bucket/o/aabb/ not found
https://objectstorage.location.oraclecloud.com/n/namespace/b/bucket/o/aabb/* not found
```

in the bucket I have some objects:

aabb/test.png

aabb/test2.png

aabc/test3.png

aabc/test4.png

how do I list objects in aabb only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add data source parameter

type: query string variable

name: prefix

value: aabb  in my case